# How to prevent/detect login from multiple devices from a single user? (Node.js | oAuth 2.0)

Tags: node.js, authentication, access-token

I have developed a token-based login system using oAuth2.0 package with node js. With this, I have tested that a particular user can log in to the system from multiple devices. I want to prevent the user from multiple device login. I would be giving the user a prompt that he/she is already logged in on another device.

Thank you.

Comment: Include in each token a unique identifier and store the identifiers per user in a database. If you receive a token with identifier A but have already stored another token identifier B for the same user, reject the request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this out. I was wondering if I could get the user device, os or something like that (unique) from the api request and set that as a unique ID?

Comment: I suggest you simply generate a unique ID, for example with the [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package. The device will use the same token (with the same ID) in all requests after the login request, until logoff.